# Cascading / dependent drop down list in web2py

Tags: java, python, ajax, drop-down-menu, web2py

I'm having a few problems trying to create a cascading drop down list in web2py. I've followed this recipe, however, It is quite difficult for me (a beginner) to suss out the logic behind it.

http://www.web2pyslices.com/slice/show/1526/cascading-drop-down-lists-with-ajax-2

i've managed to adapt it slightly, but i'm having trouble trying to add more tables to the cascade/sequence

So at the moment i have the code below, what i'm trying to do is return a list of values from  the "tax_class" table based selecting results from the  "tax_phylum" table

model

```
db.define_table('tax_kingdom',
                Field('name'))

db.define_table('tax_phylum',
                Field('name', 'string'),
                Field('kingdom_id'))
db.tax_phylum.kingdom_id.requires = IS_IN_DB(db, db.tax_kingdom.id, '%(name)s')

db.define_table('tax_class',
                Field('name', 'string'),
                Field('phylum_id'))
db.tax_class.phylum_id.requires = IS_IN_DB(db, db.tax_phylum.id, '%(name)s')
```

Controller

```
def index():
    kingdoms = db().select(db.tax_kingdom.ALL)

    if request.vars.kingdom_name:
        phylum_select = db(db.tax_phylum.id == request.vars.kingdom_name).select(db.tax_phylum.ALL)
    else:
        phylum_select = db(db.tax_phylum.id == 1).select(db.tax_phylum.ALL)
    return dict(kingdoms=kingdoms, phylum_select=phylum_select)


def phylum():
    phylums = db(db.tax_phylum.kingdom_id == request.vars.kingdom_name).select(db.tax_phylum.ALL)
    result = ""
    for p in phylums:
        result += "<option value='" + str(p.id) + "'>" + p.name + "</option>"
    return XML(result)
```

view

```
{{extend 'layout.html'}}

<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="{{URL()}}" method="post">
    <select name='kingdom_name'
        onchange="jQuery('#kingdom_name').empty();
        ajax('phylum', ['kingdom_name'], 'phylum_name');">
        {{for kingdom in kingdoms:}}
            <option value="{{=kingdom.id}}"
                {{=" selected='selected'" if str(kingdom.id)==request.vars.kingdom_name else ""}}>
            {{=kingdom.name}}
            </option>
        {{pass}}
    </select>


<select id='phylum_name' name='phylum_name' >
    <!-- loop through the index function i -->
        {{for phylum in phylum_select:}}
            <option value="{{=phylum.id}}"
                {{=XML(" selected='selected'") if str(phylum.id)==request.vars.phylum_name else ""}}>
            {{=phylum.name}}</option>
        {{pass}}
    </select>


</form>
```